# How to save special characters in c# asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this `JS` code below to save the data input by a user. All data is seen in `var JsonData = JSON.stringify(data);`. I input a special character in `Task (& sign)` `[Task Value is (A & B)]`. But in my controller It cut the data before the `&` sign.

```
$('#btn_SubmitOT').live('click', function () {
    if (lastSel != -1) {
        $('#' + lastSel + '_isValidated').val(true);
        //            $('#' + lastSel + '_RequestedBy').val();
        var datefiled = $('#ot_dateFiled').val().
        $('#' + lastSel + '_OTDateApplied').val(datefiled);
        jQuery('#grdOTApplication').saveRow(lastSel, false, 'clientArray');
    }
    var task = $("#task_ot").val();
    //var data = $("#grdOTApplication").jqGrid('getRowData');
    var data = {
        DateFiled: $("#ot_dateFiled").val(),
        DateofOvertime: $("#ot_dateOfOT").val(),
        EmployeeId: $("#empApplicants").val(),
        In1: $("#from_sup").val() + $("#from_AM_PM").val(),
        Out1: $("#to_sup").val() + $("#to_AM_PM").val(),
        EstimatedHours: $("#estimateHrsWrk_ot").val(),
        SpecificTask: task,
        ApprovedBy: $("#approveofficial").val() != null ? $("#approveofficial").val() : 0,
        RecommendedBy: $("#recommenders").val() != null ? $("#recommenders").val() : 0,
        SupervisedBy: $("#immediatesupervisor").val() != null ? $("#immediatesupervisor").val() : 0,
        IsCOC: $('#cmbCO').val() == 1 ? true : false
    }


    var JsonData = JSON.stringify(data);

    var urlPA = '../Request/saveOvertimeRequest?overtimeRequest=' + JsonData + '&_role = 3;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: urlPA,
        success: function (response) {
            alert(response);
            $("#grdOTApplication").trigger("reloadGrid", [{
                current: true
            }]);
            $("#grdOTHistory").trigger("reloadGrid", [{
                current: true
            }]);
            $("#ot_dateOfOT").val("");
            $("#from_sup").val("__:__");
            $("#to_sup").val("__:__");
            $("#estimateHrsWrk_ot").val("");
            $("#task_ot").val("");
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert("Error");
        },
        datatype: "text"
    });
});
```

Here is my Controller code I put a breakpoint and debug it why after the it reach in this code `ovt = jss.Deserialize<OvertimeRequest>((string)overtimeRequest);` it direct to the `catch`. And as I mention above it it cuts the data before the the `&` sign.

```
public String saveOvertimeRequest(String overtimeRequest, int _role)
    {
        Nullable<DateTime> MyNullableDate = null;
        try
        {
            Int32 requestedBy = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["PersonId"]);
            Int32 empId = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["EmpId"]);

            OvertimeRequest ovt = new OvertimeRequest();
            JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            ovt = jss.Deserialize<OvertimeRequest>((string)overtimeRequest);
            ovt.IsFromESS = true;
            ovt.RequestedBy = requestedBy;
            if (_role == 3 || ((ovt.SupervisedBy == 0 || ovt.SupervisedBy == null) && ovt.RecommendedBy > 0 && ovt.ApprovedBy > 0))
            {
                ovt.SupervisedBy = null;
                ovt.DateSupervised = DateTime.Now;

            }
            if (_role == 4 || ((ovt.SupervisedBy == 0 || ovt.SupervisedBy == null) && (ovt.RecommendedBy == 0 || ovt.RecommendedBy == null) && ovt.ApprovedBy > 0))
            {
                ovt.SupervisedBy = null;
                ovt.DateSupervised = DateTime.Now;
                ovt.RecommendedBy = null;
                ovt.DateRecommend = DateTime.Now;

            }
            if (_role == 5 || ((ovt.SupervisedBy == 0 || ovt.SupervisedBy == null) && (ovt.RecommendedBy == 0 || ovt.RecommendedBy == null) && (ovt.ApprovedBy == 0 || ovt.ApprovedBy == null)))
            {
                ovt.SupervisedBy = null;
                ovt.DateSupervised = DateTime.Now;
                ovt.RecommendedBy = null;
                ovt.DateRecommend = DateTime.Now;
                ovt.ApprovedBy = null;
                ovt.DateApproved = DateTime.Now;
                ovt.IsPosted = true;
                ovt.DatePosted = DateTime.Now;
            }
            try
            {
                db.AddToOvertimeRequests(ovt);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
          }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return "An error has occured while sending your request.";
        }
    }
```

[image: JS]

[image: Control]

Answer (score 2):

You are loosing the data because you are doing a GET request. When you do GET call, The data will be sent as querystring and `&` has a special meaning when it is in querystring. It is a seperator for different querystring items.

What you should be doing is, making a POST call to the server. Also there is no need to explicitly doing the deserialization as model binder does that for you. Just create a C# POCO class which represent the structure of data you are sending and use that as your action method parameter.

```
public class OverTimeViewModel
{
  public DateTime DateFiled { set;get;}
  public DateTime DateofOvertime { set;get;}
  public int EstimatedHours { set;get;}
  //Add other properties here
}
```

and in the javascript code, use POST as the ajax method.

```
var viewModel = {
                  DateFiled: '12/12/2012'
                  EstimatedHours : 10
                } ;
// values hard coded for demo. Replace with real values
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: urlPA,
    data : viewModel 
    success: function (response) {
      //do something with the response
    }
});
```

Now make sure you use the view model we created as the parameter

```
public ActionResult SaveOvertimeRequest(OverTimeViewModel model)
{
  //check model.DateField etc and use 
}
```

Comment: If I use this method can all special characters can be save?

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out thanks to all who view my post.

I use this code `var task =escape($("#task_ot").val());`